# Solving problem with stacked bar chart with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart with a percentage structure. Below you can see a small example of my data.

```
df<-structure(list(Year = c("2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
                        "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), Age = c("Children", 
                                                                                         "Adults", "Children", "Adults", "Children", 
                                                                                         "Adults", "Children", "Adults", "Children", 
                                                                                         "Adults", "Children", "Adults"), Country = structure(c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Aruba", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Benin", "Burundi", "Kongo", "Mali", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Nigeria"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.421052631578947, 0.578947368421053, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.25, 0.75, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.705263157894737, 0.294736842105263), color = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("red", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "royalblue"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

The structure of adults and children in each country is 1. Now I want to make a bar chart with Plotly. I tried with this code below :

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~list(Year,Country), y = ~value, 
                color = ~Age, colors = ~as.character(color), type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack",
         title = 'Title',
         xaxis = list(title = 'Percentage'), 
         yaxis = list(title = ' '))
```

Instead of a stacked bar chart with percentages, this code gives something different. Below you can see an example.
[image]

So probably error is somewhere in the data but I can't find where (e.g factors etc). So can anybody help how to solve this problem and make bar chart with 100% percentage for each country ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://plotly.com/r/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart) one option would be to reshape your data to wide format and use a second trace:

```r
library(plotly)

df <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(-color)  %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Age, values_from = value)

plot_ly(df,
  x = ~ list(Year, Country), y = ~Children,
  type = "bar", marker = list(
    color = "royalblue"
  ), name = "Children"
) %>%
  add_bars(y = ~Adults, marker = list(
    color = "red"
  ), name = "Adults")  %>%
  layout(
    barmode = "stack",
    title = "Title",
    xaxis = list(title = "Percentage"),
    yaxis = list(title = " ")
  )
```

[image]